# recover HD overwritten by ddrescue

Tags: hard-drive, 20.04, data-recovery, testdisk

I have a portable 2TB hard disk that I was using as a network drive.  I had disconnected it from the router and connected it via USB to my desktop.  It contained all my pictures.  I was working on organizing all the photos and adding old ones from DVDs. With the pictures and other data, I was up to 90gb.
 I was having trouble with reading files off of a DVD, so I used gddrescue to try to recover the photos off that disk. I didn't do my due diligence and instead of putting the Log file on the HD, I copied the cd to the HD. OOPS.  :(

Nautilus can now only see the HD as a 2.5gb drive holding only a "Pictures" directory.  Gparted and Disks see the HD as a 2tb external HD, but only thing I can mount is the 2.5gb cd copy.  Is there any way I can recover the pictures and other data on the HD?

Comment: Did you check out testdisk?  Of course, you'll lose the first 2.5G that was overwritten.

Comment: Howdy Well since I wrote that I did a little more research and I found on another forum a method that I am going to try. They recommended that I copy the original hard drive to a second and then work on the copy. Supposedly that's what the forensic folks do. I bought an identical external hard drive and am using gddrescue :o to copy the original to the new one and will use testdisk to try to get the files off of the copy. As of now its 19 hours into the copy process with 15 hours to go.....

Comment: Ouch, bitten by the slow copy bug.  I recently found that nocache from the nocache package helps keep the system buffers from filling up and dragging the system response down to zilch.